# Gitlab CI: How to avoid rebuilding of images on each commit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-build

I'm using Gitlab CI to store and deploy docker images but I got a big issue. Gitlab CI is rebuilding all images on every commit.

The first step is to build my common image which takes around 8 minutes. Currently I only modify child images but the common image is still rebuild on every commit.

Thus the build is a waste of time because the push won't have an effect as the image is already inside the Gitlab repository.

How to avoid the rebuild of images when it's already inside your Gitlab repository?

Below gitlab-ci.yml

```
build:
   tags:
       - docker_ci_build
   services:
       - docker:dind
   script:
       - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
       - >
           docker build 
           -t $CI_PROJECT/common:6.0.1 common
```

Below a dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt-get update && \
     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
     apt-get install -y packages && \
     apt-get clean && \
     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY file.conf /etc/common/
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing a representative `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I edited the first post. But I did new search and it seems its not possible. The only way is to pull image from your registry before the build. But its makes your build fails if the image does not exist yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching appears to be more complicated than what I first thought, and the docker documentation for the various pull options fails to mention any nuances.

If the docker image may or may not yet exist, you can actually adjust the docker pull command to pass your build even if the pull fails:

```
- docker image pull $LATEST || true
```

This will pull the image $LATEST if it exists, otherwise will carry on with your build. The next step is to make sure that your build can actually take use of it.

The `--pull` option for docker build seemed like what you wanted, and docker's documentation says

> --pull        Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image

but it appears that it doesn't actually do anything for the actual image you're building. More promising is `--cache-from` which lets you name images that docker can cache from. In my simple test however, I was not seeing docker actually use my cache, probably because it doesn't have enough layers in the docker image to leverage the cache.

```
- docker image pull $LATEST_IMAGE || true
- docker build --pull -t $TAGGED_IMAGE --cache-from $LATEST_IMAGE .
- docker tag $TAGGED_IMAGE $LATEST_IMAGE
- docker push $LATEST_IMAGE
- docker push $TAGGED_IMAGE
```

This may be more useful if your build image is [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) build, and can actually leverage the cache. Optionally, you could adjust your gitlab-ci script to avoid building if the image exists.

Optionally, you may want to look at gitlab-ci pipelines and creating optional stages and triggers for when you build and push common, and when you build your sub-projects.

I define the variables in a `variables` section at the beginning of the file
Latest is defined with the `:latest` tag which is basically the most recent build from any CI branch for the project. `$TAGGED_IMAGE` is defined with `:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` which tags the docker image with the git SHA, which makes kubernetes deployments to a development environment easier to track.

Comment: ```docker build --pull``` is not working. I got a complete build on every commit with no changes.

Comment: Are you pushing and pulling from your private docker registry as part of gitlab? I don't recall seeing `$CI_PROJECT` defined in gitlab's list of CI variables: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

Comment: I push/pull in gitlab registry CI_PROJECT is custom variable at the beginning of my gitlab_ci.yml equals to CI_PROJECT_URL without https://.

Comment: I've added some more information, you might try `docker image pull $NAME || true`. Does your build actually leverage image caching, or are you trying to only build the image if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Yeah it works.  || true permits to continue job if image does not exist. The --cache-from is mandatory in build command. Thanks